# Where to put code for hardware configuration in movesense Firmware Application/Whiteboard?

Tags: movesense

I want to configure the max30003 chip only once at the beginning of the measurement. But I dont understand the structure, when my code is executed. I have a Modul "TestModul" in App.cpp by MOVESENSE_PROVIDER_DEF. 
In the cpp of TestModul I have some functions to change the registers of max30003 as described in the documentation https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-docs/wiki/EmbeddedSoftware/api/components/max3000x.

Are they going to be executed, everytime the modul is executed? Where do i have to put them? Init / Start Modul in testmodul.cpp ? When is the modul executed? Is there something like a main function?

Code og testmodul.hpp
private:
    // INIT MODUL
    virtual bool initModule() OVERRIDE;

```
// DEINIT MODUL
virtual void deinitModule() OVERRIDE;

// START MODUL
virtual bool startModule() OVERRIDE;

// STOP MODUL
virtual void stopModule() OVERRIDE { mModuleState = WB_RES::ModuleStateValues::STOPPED; }

// WB Provider onGETREQUEST
virtual void onGetRequest(..) OVERRIDE;

// WB Client onPutResult
virtual void onPutResult(..) OVERRIDE;

void writeMAX3000xRegister();
```

};

Answer (score 0):

If you add your setup code in startModule() it will be run when the sensor starts after the framework services have started up.

*Full Disclaimer: I work for the Movesense team*